# Ceasar cypher part 2

Tags: python, encryption

Caeser Cypher Part II - ok so this is an advance from last weeks work for my a level work, now need to make a fully working ceasar cypher which can encypt a sentence by a certain shift value. Im not sure what to do next .. can any one help, also why am i running a traceback error on alphabet line 19, python says 'alphabet' is not defined when i defined it?

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter a sentence to be encrypted')
shift = input('Enter a shift value')

def createDict (shift):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ,'

alphaList=[]
for letter in alphabet:
    alphaList.append(letter)

alphaDict={}
for letter in alphaList:
    valueLetterIndex = (alphaList.index(letter) + shift)%len(alphaList)
    valueLetter = alphaList[valueLetterIndex]
    alphaDict[letter] = valueLetter
```

Comment: Please add more details about the error you get.

Comment: It's not defined. You defined it in a function then tried to access it outside of the function. Perhaps your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Look at my answer on your last question. It does what you want.

Comment: I know you gave the answer but i want to do it with some help along the way not just given the answer, any prompts on what i have to do next??

Answer (score 3):

You created a local variable `alphabet` inside of the `createDict()` function, but...

- You never call this function
- Even if you did, `alphabet` would still not be defined in the global scope where you try to access it

Try just removing the `createDict` function definition and un-indenting the `alphabet` definition line:

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter a sentence to be encrypted')
shift = input('Enter a shift value')

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ,'

alphaDict={}
for letter in alphabet:
    valueLetterIndex = (alphabet.index(letter) + shift)%len(alphabet)
    valueLetter = alphabet[valueLetterIndex]
    alphaDict[letter] = valueLetter
```

Or maybe you actually intended to have everything inside of that function, in which case you need to add a level of indentation to everything below the `alphabet` definition.

As a side note, you could simplify your `alphaList` construction to `list(alphabet)`, or just use `alphabet` instead of `alphaList` as suggested by Kevin.

Comment: As a side note to his side note, you don't really need `alphaList` at all. Strings support iteration and `index` and `len` the same as lists, so just use `alphabet`.

Comment: What do i have to do next im confused

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `createDict()` function? This is very weird. You don't use it at all. 
Secondly, I love iPython. This is invaluable tool.

```
  6 
  7 alphaList=[]
----> 8 for letter in alphabet:
  9   alphaList.append(letter)
  10 

  NameError: name 'alphabet' is not defined
```

You see it now. And I think there is a easier way to do this. 
Did you try builtin function `ord()` and `chr()` and simple list.

```
list = list('Your string')
text_to_encode = raw_input('Prompt') 
text_to_encode = list(text_to_encode)
for i in text_to_encode:
    in = (ord(text_to_encode)-65)
    code = (ord(text_to_encode)-65) 
    if in+code > 26:
        foo = code - in
        text_to_encode[i] = foo
    else:
        foo = code+in
```

This is only pseudocode. 
Try something similar. 
This will work only for small letter. For upper letter you must add few elifs.

Comment: But we're not allowed to use the ord and chr functions yet

Answer (score 1):

```
def ceasar(s, n):
    # The characters in skipchars are not changed. Expand to your liking.
    skipchars = ' .,?/!@#$%^&*()[]{}'
    s = s.lower()
    t = ord('a')
    out = ''
    for c in s:
        if not c in skipchars:
            out += chr((ord(c)-t+n)%26 + t)
        else:
            out += c
    return out
```

To test it, we use 13 as the offset:

```
In [21]: ceasar('This is a test.', 13)
Out[21]: 'guvf vf n grfg.'

In [22]: ceasar('guvf vf n grfg.', 13)
Out[22]: 'this is a test.'

In [23]: 'guvf vf n grfg.'.encode('rot13')
Out[23]: 'this is a test.'
```

Comment: What?? I'm really confused now